# Spawning WSGI example (practical approach to WSGI)

Tags: python, wsgi, wsgiserver

I'm trying to understand how WSGI works. I know I could read the specs, but I'd still want to know how do I create a [spawning](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning) application? A complete "hello world".

Could someone show me an example?
With everything, file naming, creating the module, running it. Every and each step. Thanks.

(NB: while spawning seems a great piece of software, it has a stupid name: I cannot find anything successfully on the web on the matter, because everything related to "spawning" also relates to "multithreading" or "IPC").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see in the documentation, Spawning just runs stock WSGI apps, which means that you just write a [WSGI script](http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/wsgi-intro/what-is-wsgi.html) and then invoke Spawning against it:

```
spawn helloworld.simple_app
spawn helloworld.simple_app middleware.Upperware
```

As always, make sure you have installed any modules it depends on, such as [`paste.deploy`](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/).

Comment: I did read the documentation and I did experimented around, but I can't figure out how to write it exactly. Please improve your answer.

Comment: Save the first snippet under "An example WSGI application" as helloworld.py, the second snippet as middleware.py, and run the above commands.

Comment: The things I've tried give me: "ImportError: No module named paste.deploy", including that example.

Comment: There's no "paste.deploy" on pypi. I did install paste with easy_install and now it only says: "ImportError: No module named deploy", in an endless loop, like it did earlier with "paste.deploy".

Comment: I've fixed it by looking on the GIT repository of spawning, last log says it depends on "pastedeploy". Please add this to your response as well as the second comment, so I can accept your answer. Thanks!